# dynamically creating a table and adding cells to the table through a function with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, function, dynamic

I am wondering how to create a function with a for loop which creates new cells / rows for the other for loop to call upon. The function should return newRow which should be a specified amount of cells. The idea is the html code displays 3 images per row, but if there is just 2 images then it only needs 2 cells. That is the first if / else statement.

Here is the code so far..

```
 var cells = document.getElementsByTagName('td');
 var cell = '<td>' + cells[0].innerHTML + '</td>';
 //console.log(cell);


 document.getElementById('searchBtn').onclick = search;

 //specified as 3 per row
 var NUMPERROW = 3;

 //gets number from form text input
 var num = document.getElementById("searchtxt").value;

 function search(){

//var num = 4;

console.log(num);

//loop once per row
var htmlStr = '';
for (var i = 0; i < num; i = i + NUMPERROW){

    //htmlStr += '<tr>' + cell + cell + cell + '</tr>;
    if (num - i >= NUMPERROW) {

        //displays a new row of 3 
        htmlStr += newRow(NUMPERROW);

    }else { //less then 3 to display

        htmlStr += newRow(num - i);
    }


} 
document.getElementById('thumbnails').innerHTML = htmlStr;


}
/*
*Returns the html for a new row.
* numToAdd: the number of cells to add for this row.
*
*/
//this function i do not know how to write

function newRow(cellsToAdd){

 /////?????????? should be a for loop return new Row for the for loop above

}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple function if you don't want to pass the values you can leave `content` out.

```
function newRow(numberOfCells, content)
{
var result = '<tr>';
for(var i = 0; i < numberOfCells; i++)
    result += '<td>' + content[i] + '</td>';
result += '</tr>';
return result;
}
```